# Where can I get the original PCM data from the Android framework?

Tags: android, c++, media, pcm

Where can I get the original pcm data from the Android framework?
I think I can get it from:

```
Write (const void * buffer, size_t userSize, bool blocking)
```

in `/framework/av/media/libmedia/AudioTrack.cpp`

However, it differs from the pcm data in the file before streaming service and the pcm data obtained in write.

I think it is like re-sampling.

Where can I get original pcm data?

Note:

- The sound source is a FLAC sound source.
- The Android version is 6.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

You have better chance of tapping the `pcm` buffer at one layer below the android-framework layer - audio hal. Now that would be dependent on the hardware hence I can provide you with some *probable* examples:-

`hardware/xxx/audio/hal/audio_hw.c` (Where xxx is qcom in my case)
  `in_read()` --> `pcm_read()`

`external/tinyalsa/pcm.c`
  `pcm_read()`

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.

Let's try a test.

But what is the difference between the PCM data in the audio HAL and the PCM data in the AudioTrack.cpp?

Answer (score 0):

PCM data in AudioTrack.cpp will be entered to AudioMixer and AudioEffects components to customise effects and then into audio HAL.